# silverlight 3: How to create a resizable childwindow?

Tags: silverlight, silverlight-toolkit

Is there any way to create a resizable childwindow in silverlight 3? Any pointers are highly appreciated.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I don't have any actual code for you, but you would probably want to subclass ChildWindow and handle the MouseLeftButtonDown, MouseMove, and MouseLeftButtonUp mouse events within a certain "border" of the edge of the ChildWindow or within a certain "grip" region (such as the lower-right corner).

You would want to use some [standard drag and drop logic](http://wildermuth.com/2009/02/09/Drag_and_Drop_in_Silverlight_2) to detect that a drag is being performed for a resize and update `this.Width` and `this.Height` based on the relative mouse coordinates using the `GetPosition()` method of the MouseEventArgs class.

You might also want to have a look at the [FloatableWindow](http://floatablewindow.codeplex.com/) control on CodePlex, which is a refactored version of the ChildWindow which supports drag and drop moving and resizing.

Answer (score 2):

Take a look at Tim Huer's FloatableWindow.  I think this might do what you are looking for.

http://timheuer.com/blog/archive/2009/07/08/silverlight-floatablewindow-updated-with-resizing-capabilities.aspx